# ie9 sucks at loading

Tags: internet-explorer-9

I'm testing a web app for compatability with IE9, the thing is that it takes ages to load. It works fine on other people's computers and loads like lightning in firefox. I have stopped my antivirus from messing with the browser and disabled all IE9's addons. I just recently upgraded to IE9 after IE8 gave me the same problem. Can you think of anything else to try?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a development issue, so much as an environmental one -- maybe try posting your question on ServerFault or similar?

Comment: I now have the same problem (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12174169/ie9-hangs-backbone-jquery-visualsearch-webapp-hanging-only-with-ie9) maybe we can talk...

Answer (score 0):

I saw something similar to this once.  It turned out it had something to do with how IE sets up for automatic logon.

I kept getting certificate related errors in the domain controller.  Turned out the domain certificate (or something like this) was out of date and the certificate authority was not started.  So we started the certificate authority and updated the domain (?) certificates.  IE started working much faster.  This was back in the old IE7 days.  I don't remember the solution that well but you might investigate what's happening in your domain, if you have one.